# How to update path from within instance method?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});

// this is the instance method which should update the document name.
schema.method('changeName', function(name) {
  this.name = name;
});

var Model = mongoose.model('Person', schema);

var doc = new Model();
doc.name = 'initial value';

// this should change the doc's name to `new value`.
doc.changeName('new value');

doc.save(function(err, obj) {
  // this will print `initial value` while it should print `new value`.
  console.log(obj.name);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test your codes as below

```
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function() {
    isSeenConnected = true;
    console.log('Establish connection to mongoDB');
    saveData();
});

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});

// this is the instance method which should update the document name.
schema.method('changeName', function(name) {
  this.name = name;
});

var Model = mongoose.model('Person', schema);

function saveData() {
    var doc = new Model();
    doc.name = 'initial value';

    doc.changeName('new value');

    console.log(doc);
    doc.save(function(err, obj) {
      console.log(obj.name);
    }); 
}
```

Output:

```
Establish connection to mongoDB
{ name: 'new value', _id: 56adb56e7bb2f49f02d18d8e }
Open connection to mongoDB
new value
```

It seems work well...

Comment: You are right, it didn't work because I used **this** in **lodash.forEach**.